# How to stop a compiler from assuming octal?

Tags: gcc

I have some autogenerated code.  The code is for a MCU, so it has some timing constraints that don't allow for loops, which means I generate some code such as this:

```
pa_result[06] = pa_positive[06] - pa_negative[06];
pa_result[07] = pa_positive[07] - pa_negative[07];
pa_result[08] = pa_positive[08] - pa_negative[08];  //<--terrible things
pa_result[09] = pa_positive[09] - pa_negative[09];  //<--terrible things
pa_result[10] = pa_positive[10] - pa_negative[10];
pa_result[11] = pa_positive[11] - pa_negative[11];
```

The compiler sees `08` and `09` and assumes octal.  However, it makes no such assumptions for any other number.

Is there a prefix to say "not octal"? (also, why just with `08` and `09`)

Comment: Considering that it's standard behaviour to assume octal in numbers prefixed with 0, I cannot imagine a compiler changing this to something non-complying. With that said, I would expect a compiler to at least _warn_ about this one.

Comment: @E_net4 it warns only on two of them.  I only noticed today because I went from 0-7 entries to 0-16.  gcc does not warn until `08`.  So, I guess that I'll just inject a space instead of a 0.  I was using %02i in the code that generated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero `0` as a leading character in a number is the C standard way to define that what follows is an octal number. The reason only `08` and `09` give an error is that those are not valid octal numbers. `01` - `07` are all valid octal numbers which represent the same decimal numbers 1 - 7 that you would expect. This is for the same reason that hex numbers `0x0` - `0x9` look the same as 0 - 9 decimal, so long as you ignore the `0x` which indicates hexadecimal digits follow.

However, `8` and `9` are not a valid octal digits, in the same way that `A` is not a valid decimal digit, even though in hex it is perfectly fine, representing decimal 10.

You will need to remove the leading zero `0` for them to be considered decimal numbers, and work as expected.